# Microphone on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS stopped working

Tags: sound, permissions, pulseaudio, microphone

Suddenly, my Lenovo Ideapad 310 microphone on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS stopped working.

Context:

1. The microphone works well in Windows 10, so it is not a hardware problem, but a software problem.
2. I do have sound output, for example I can listen to music in YouTube.
3. A similar problem happened in another old laptop, but miraculously it solved itself after some days.
4. After searching many times in AskUbuntu, I could not find how to get the microphone working again.

After reading AskUbuntu I opened a terminal and ran:

```
sudo pulseaudio
```

And got the following response:

```
[pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
```

It looks like a permissions issue, but in AskUbuntu using `chmod` was discouraged and I found no recommended solution.

How do I fix the microphone not working issue? I would like to solve the problem. I use my microphone a lot for teaching and taking classes.

Comment: I have faced same problem. I Install Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS before 3 days. Microphone device not working . I search but not found any soultion. Before that all things working.

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Memory 11.6 GiB

Processor Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 

Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)

GNOME 3.28.2

Os Type 64-bit
Disk 235.2 GB

Comment: I use Gnome to, it is version 3.28.2 too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I do not know exactly what solved it but some of it worked and this it what I did:

First I installed the synaptic package manager, which was present as a default in earlier ubuntu versions.

Then I looked up "microphone" in the synaptic search box.

I realized that there were some microphone apps and marked them for installation, I don't remember quite well, but they might be: jnoisemeter, apulse, gnome-alsamixer.

Ubuntu needed to install 3 missing packages.

Then I managed to record something with Cheese Webcam Booth, but at a very very low volume.

After that I tried with Zoom and the microphone was taking in sound ok!!!! It works.

To be sure that volume output I checked with a youtube recording.

Now I am trying to use record my desktop.